# Socket.io Timer that displays in minutes, seconds

Tags: javascript, arrays, socket.io, countdowntimer

Here i am trying to create a timer that counts down from a specified value in m:s format, when the timer reaches 0 i want to emit to the clients using a function called selectUser. My HTML and Script.js are working fine. I'm just missing something here, because the numbers aren't decrementing properly, and the emit isn't firing.

```
var timerCall = function() {};
var countdown = 30000;
var minutes;
var seconds;
setInterval(function() {
    minutes = Math.floor(countdown / 6000); // 7
    seconds = countdown % 60; // 30
    timerCall(minutes, seconds, countdown);
    if (seconds > 0) {
            seconds --;
    }
}, 1000);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('reset', function(data) {
        countdown = 30000;
        io.sockets.emit('timer', {
            countdown: countdown
        });
    });
    timerCall = function(minutes, seconds, countdown) {


        if (countdown === 0) {
            selectUser(myarr, myarr2, myarr3, myarr4);
        };
        if (seconds === 0) {
            minutes--;
            seconds = 59;
        }
        io.sockets.emit('timer', {
            countdown: minutes + ':' + seconds
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help, this is my first post on StackOverflow. So be nice ;)

Comment: Hi @Dan, could you elaborate on "*the numbers aren't decrementing properly*"? What *is* happening to the numbers, if anything?. Also, isn't *everybody* nice to everybody else on StackOverflow? ;)

Comment: @WaiHaLee The numbers aren't decrementing at all, they are just stuck on 4:59